# How to get taskid after the complete method

Tags: java, activiti

I have a workflow like: startevent -> task1(Assignee:Tom) -> choose sequence flow "agree"  ->task2(Assignee:Jerry) -> choose sequence flow "disagree"  -> task1

When the flow arrive to task1, i want to set assignee to "Tom" again.

Now i have an idea like:

When the flow arrive to task1, i use complete method, after the complete method, set a local variable "pre_task_id(task1's taskid)" in task2 so that i can use task1's taskid to search in "act_hi_taskinst" table for assignee(Tom), but  this method `taskService.setVariableLocal(taskId, variableName, value)` need task2's taskid, how can i get the task2's taskid after complete method?

```
@Test
public void testCompleteTask() {
    Task task = taskService.createTaskQuery().taskAssignee("Tom").singleResult();
    if (task == null) {
        System.out.println("no task!!!");
        return;
    }
    String preTaskId = task.getId();
    HashMap <String,Object> variables = new HashMap<>();
    variables.put("userId", "Jerry");
    variables.put("oper", "saolu");
    taskService.complete(task.getId(),variables);
    //don't konw how to get the taskId 
    //taskService.setVariableLocal(taskId, "pre_task_id", preTaskId);
}
```

I am using activiti6

Or please let me konw if there are any better solutions

[workflow.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwGaK.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to help us help you, please include a [minimal reproduceable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can give you a hand!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand properly. You need to keep track which task is executed most recently.
In that case you can use a stack. When ever you execute any task you just call the push with the task id.
When ever you call pop it will give you the task id of the most recent task executed.
Just be careful about how you want to clear the stack as well.
I would recommend to always call pop before calling push.

Comment: I am also worried about the situation mentioned below, but thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have always used a process variable for this purpose, Have never attempted the "push" operation suggested above but I would be concerned about getting the correct value back if multiple parallel processes are all pushing/pulling to and from the stack at once. The process variable is simple and I know it works.

Comment: Please tell me more about using process variable for this purpose.